# Electron-builder add a third party .pkg to the .DMG

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm currently using electron-builder to create my .dmg file for distribution on the Mac, but I want to add an additional .pkg file So when the user opens the .Dmg they will see both the Application icon and the .pkg file. This way they can drag my application and also click on the .pkg which is a third party software they need.  How can I configure that in the config?

I tried looking at the documentation found here, but it was not very helpful in this scenario.
https://www.electron.build/configuration/dmg